# SpatialFullConvolution (torch) in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, torch

I try to translate a torch code to TensorFlow, but I cannot find the corresponding tensorflow function of SpatialFullConvolution which is able to apply transpose convoluation on vector (not only image).

How can I deal with it?
here is an example https://github.com/soumith/dcgan.torch/blob/master/main.lua

Answer (score 0):

SpatialFullConvolution in torch is same as Transposed Convolution/Deconvolution/Fractionally strided convolution. You can find the Keras documentation [here](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#conv2dtranspose)